# Should we [join] this tag with the other burninated ones?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I've just again realized that we have a [join](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/join) tag, which corresponds to SQL.  It doesn't appear that the questions have anything else in common, either.  Do we still need it?

Answer (score 9):

No, your statement that [join](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/join) is related to [sql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) is a faulty assumption.

There are also questions about performing joins with [excel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel), [csv](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csv), [pandas](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pandas), or just joining data the hard way in regular programming languages.

While it is true that most interesting [sql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) queries involve some kind of `JOIN`, that is not universally true. (Many `INSERT` and `UPDATE` queries do not involve `JOIN`, for example.)  It is debatable whether those uses of the [join](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/join) tag are worth eliminating.  I'd say that they are harmless to leave there.

Answer (score 1):

## Burn it.

Pretty much all SQL queries use joins in one form or another. I think that having [sql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) is on its own sufficient and it should be assumed that any SQL question could have joins, making the use of [sql](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) [join](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/join) together redundant.